# How can I save an Outlook forwarded meeting invitation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, forwarding, meetings

Folks forward me meeting invitations as Outlook attachments.  We use Microsoft Outlook Professional Plus.

I can pop open the attachment and see a lot of things there about forwarding the meeting, etc. but there is no option to add it to my calendar.  Any ideas how to do that besides cutting and pasting all the fields?

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure if you can save it unless you are invited by the originator. Have you tried to drag the attachment from the email to the calendar?

Comment: Which version of Outlook (2007, 2010, for example)

Answer (score 0):

As CharlieRB mentioned in the comments:
Opening the FWD in a new window and dragging the calendar icon into your calendar should work.